# Datepicker: minDate changes selected date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am changing minDate of jquery datepicker based on some condition. It changes the current date as well if the current date is lesser than minDate. That is as expected. Ofcourse it doesn't fire onSelect since the date is not selected but changed internally.

Is there a way to catch the change of this date?

Comment: You can use the Change event of the textbox.

Comment: can you show the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Did this today to solve this:

```
target.datepicker({ showOn: 'none', dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' }); // config

var focus = function() {
  var currentValue = input.value;
  target.datepicker('option', 'minDate', '31.10.2017'); // set minDate
  target.datepicker('show');
  input.value = currentValue; // set value back to orginal
}

input.addEventListener('focus', focus); // listen to input focus
```